# setup-config.php gets to step 1 then returns 403 forbidden

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx

I am working on setting up a Wordpress website, and stumbled upon an interesting issue that doesn't seem to want to give up.

The problem that is appearing is that `setup-config.php` in the Wordpress installation gets to http://example.com/setup-config.php?step=1, then I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Also, the page looks as if it doesn't have any styling, and console is telling me that all JS files and style files are also forbidden.

[image: image of the errors]

I have tried the following to fix the problem:

```
chmod 777 /path/to/website -R
chown www-data:www-data /path/to/website -R
```

None of these work. I also do not have SELinux installed, which I saw was giving other people problems as well.

```
$ selinuxenabled && echo enabled || echo disabled
The program 'selinuxenabled' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install selinux-utils
disabled
```

Here are some notable things about the server:

- Ubuntu 16.04.5
- Nginx 1.10.3
- MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.23
- Webmin 1.890

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Comment: What is your root path in your nginx conf file ?

Comment: The /home/websites/[the website]. The actual wordpress installation is a sub-folder inside the root folder. Don't know if this has an impact on that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem didn't really lie in the server-side of things. It was the Sophos firewall that was 403'ing it.

It was set on `Advanced Protection`, which blocked the PHP, JS and CSS files. Somehow, this didn't happen to the root folder of the website.

The firewall is now set to `Basic Protection` and it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

If You are Using a Wordpress on public_html and You Are Using the All In One WP Security or Wordfence Security Plugins on This Wordpress Site, Disable These Plugins. (This Method Offers a Solution For Those Who Want to Install Wordpress in Different Folders Into public_html.)